# JQuery События ввода # или @

Tags: jquery, события

В поле ввода нужно отслеживать ввод символов **#** или **@**. Если они введены - подтягиваем соответственные списки по аякс запросу.

```
$jq( "#target" ).keyup(function(e) {
                   console.log(e.which);
                });
```

Как отследить символ? По коду символа как выше? Но коректно сравнивать сам символ а не код с клавиатуры(разная раскладка, сочетания с шифтом и т.д), как это сделать? И еще нужно взять во внимание, что перед этими символамы либо ничего не должно быть либо пустой символ.

Как вообще реализовывают даный функционал и если есть уже готовые плагины, как они называются?

Comment: то что я искал называется input autocomplete или mantion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обратите внимание на свойство `key` у события:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent
в Нем содержится символ, который был введен:

```
$jq( "#target" ).keyup(function(e) {
     console.log(e.key);
});
```